# Youtube player API on android doesn't work well anymore

Tags: android, api, networking, youtube, android-mediaplayer

My android application which built with Youtube player api was working fine until around Sep. 26.

I'm encountering a message that says "There was a problem with the network [400]"

I run my application on galaxy2, Take lte and new nexus 7
and I found many trouble about Android Youtubu application
http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/youtube/playing-and-watching-videos/1ChbJPgFE0s

I think Youtube server has some problem What did they do!

anyone have troubleshooting? Thank you in advance.

=================================================================================

today I found new things

When I rerun my application on device 
It say "There was a problem with the network [400]" again
and then when I try again, It's working fine! it shows videos

but after 2 videos, I got error messages that says "Unfortunately, 'application name' has stoped" and then "Unfortunately, Youtube has stopped" with advertising sound in background
lol it's so funny and my user go away

sorry poor english (I'm not native speaker)